# VHDL Compile error

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, vhdl

trying to figure out why this VHDL code keeps giving back compile errors. I cannot get it to like the code no matter what I try.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity LabM5 is
  port(
     X : in STD_LOGIC;
     Y : in STD_LOGIC;
     Z : out STD_LOGIC
     );
end LabM5;

architecture behv of LabM5 is
begin
  process(X, Y)
    begin
        if (X='1' and Y='1')then Z='1'; end if; 
    end process;

end behv;
```

errors are:

```
Error: COMP96_0015: Lab M5.vhd : (16, 30): ';' expected.
Error: COMP96_0019: Lab M5.vhd : (16, 30): Keyword "end" expected.
Error: COMP96_0019: Lab M5.vhd : (16, 40): Keyword "process" expected.
Error: COMP96_0015: Lab M5.vhd : (17, 7): ';' expected.
Error: COMP96_0016: Lab M5.vhd : (17, 14): Design unit declaration       expected.
```

line 16 is the if statement and line 17 is the end process

Answer (score 2):

Port and signal assign is made with `<=` in VHDL, so change the assign in `if` to `Z<='1'`.

Btw; when will `Z` get any other value than `'1'` ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll make that mistake many times, since the equal operators are very different than other languages.

1. **Variable**: Use `:=` to assign a value.
2. **Signal**: Use `<=` to assign a value.
3. **Starting Value**: Use `:=` to assign the starting value, even if you're defining a signal.